# Matrix pencil with determinant equal to zero and a symmetry condition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-pencil

Let $\hat M(\vec x)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_k\hat M_k$ be an $n\times n$ matrix pencil such that $\det M(\vec x)=0$ for every $\vec x$. The $n$ matrices $\hat M_k$ are linearly independent, that is, $\vec M(\vec x)$ is not equal to zero for every $\vec x$. Furthermore, we have that $\hat M(\vec x)\vec y=\hat M(\vec y)\vec x$ for every $\vec x$ and $\vec y$. I want to prove that there is a vector $\vec z\ne\vec 0$ such that
$\vec z^t \hat M(\vec x)=0$ for every $\vec x$.

If this conjecture is correct, it would be also nice to weaken the hypotheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. I think this is better discussed using tensors or trilinear forms, not matrices, so let me change the language.

Denote $F(\vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{z}) = \vec{z}^t \hat{M}(\vec{x}) \vec{y}$. Clearly, $F$ is linear in each of the three vectors. We can go back to $\hat{M}(\vec{x}) = (m_{ij}(\vec{x}))$ by setting $m_{ij}(\vec{x}) = F(\vec{x}, \vec{e}_i, \vec{e}_j)$, where $\vec{e}_i$ are basis vectors.

Now the symmetry condition becomes $F(x, y, -) = F(y, x, -)$, $\det \hat{M}(x) = 0$ means that for each $x$ the rank of the bilinear form $F(x, -, -)$ is less than $n$, and we want to show that $F(-, -, z) = 0$ for some $z \neq 0$.

We only need symmetry in $x, y$, but the counterexample will actually be fully symmetric in all three variables. Take $n = 5$ and
$$\begin{aligned}F(x, y, z)
=\, & x_0 y_0 z_2 + (x_0 y_1 + x_1 y_0) z_3 + x_1 y_1 z_4 \\
+\, & x_0 z_0 y_2 + (x_0 z_1 + x_1 z_0) y_3 + x_1 z_1 y_4 \\
+\, & y_0 z_0 x_2 + (y_0 z_1 + y_1 z_0) x_3 + y_1 z_1 x_4 \\
\end{aligned}$$
This example is adapted from a classical example of a cubic form with vanishing hessian determinant.

The corresponding matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}
x_2 & x_3 & x_0 & x_1 & 0 \\
x_3 & x_4 & 0 & x_0 & x_1 \\
x_0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
x_1 & x_0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & x_1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ clearly has rank $4$ and does not vanish for any nonzero $x$, so $F(-,-,z) = F(z,-,-)$ is also nonzero for every nonzero $z$. We have a counterexample.

Comment: That’s right. Again, this form is not of interest for me, but now I understand which hypotheses are necessary for proving the statement.

Comment: In particular, what happens if I require that F(x,x,z)=0 for every z has an isolated point as a solution in x? Your example does not satisfy this condition.

Comment: But you also want $F(x,x,z) = 0$ for some $z$, these two conditions are incompatible.

Comment: I mean the same x has to satisfy the equation F(x,x,z)=0 for every z, and this x is an isolated point. In other words, there are n quadratic polynomial equations in x with at least one isolated solution.

Comment: On this I need to think. It is not obvious to me that there exists $F$ such with this property which also satisfies the condition $\det (F(x,e_i,e_j)) = 0$, do you have an example?

Comment: It is enough to impose the condition that I wanted to prove. This gives n-1 polynomials in an n-1 dimensional projective space, which in general have isolated zeros.

Comment: I think in this case you might be right. To have isolated points, we need $n-1$ quadratic forms to be linearly independent, and to have determinant 0, others must be linear combinations of these $n-1$.

Comment: Anyway, with the assumption that there is an isolated point, I have a proof of the statement.